# How to put out fire particle system using water particle system?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

Anybody know how to put out fire particle system using water particle system using unity3d?

Comment: Do you have any code to show? Any try to achieve that?

Comment: deminish the fire particles based on hits from the water system?

Answer (score 0):

You need three particle systems. First is normal fire particle system. Second is water particle system. Third is particle system that represents fire that is being put out, I guess it should look like a steam or something like that.
Fire particle system should be active initially. When the fire needs to be put out, you need to activate water particle system, start the steam particle system and stop emitting of fire particle system. This will look like a fire being put out by water.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways but i would prefer to do by changing the properties of [ParticleSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html). As the Water particle reaches the fire particle, start decreasing gradually the `MaxParticles` of `Fire Particle`. I guess it will work.

[image]